# Rolling window in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a numpy array. I need a rolling window:
`[1,2,3,4,5,6]` 
 expected result for sub array length 3:
`[1,2,3] [2,3,4] [3,4,5] [4,5,6]` 
Could you please help. I am not a python dev.

Python 3.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `numpy` is not a necessity, you can just use a list comprehension. If `x` is your array, then:

```
In [102]: [x[i: i + 3] for i in range(len(x) - 2)]
Out[102]: [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
```

---

Alternatively, using `np.lib.stride_tricks`. Define a function `rolling_window` (source from [this blog](http://www.rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html)):

```
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

Call the function with `window=3`:

```
In [122]: rolling_window(x, 3)
Out[122]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 3):

This might also be interesting: The `view_as_windows()` function from the `skimage.util` module. It returns a

> rolling window view of the input n-dimensional array.

Source: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows

Directly from the linked examples (adapted for your range of numbers):

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from skimage.util import view_as_windows
>>>
>>> A = np.arange(1,7)
>>> A
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> window_shape = (3,)
>>> B = view_as_windows(A, window_shape)
>>> B.shape
(4, 3)
>>> for win in B:
        print(win)
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
```